# Proving $\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{m!^{i/m}}{i!}<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

One of this days, the user [@AspiringMat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/286445/aspiringmat) was trying to prove that, for any integer $m\ge 1$,
$$\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{m!^{i/m}}{i!}<1.$$
and asked for help here on MSE. I've spent too much of my time attempting to solve this. However when I finally got to it, I realized [he deleted the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4860230/proving-sum-i-m1-infty-fracmi-mi1)! I really don't want all my effort to be wasted, so... I'm asking and answering his question once again here. My solution is really messed up, so feel free to post your own as well.

Answer (score 7):

Its enough to prove the summation sequence is strictly decreasing.

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{m!^{i/m}}{i!} &> \sum_{i=m+2}^\infty \frac{(m+1)!^{i/(m+1)}}{i!}&\iff\\
\frac{m!^{(m+1)/m}}{(m+1)!} &> \sum_{i=m+2}^\infty \frac{(m+1)!^{i/(m+1)}}{i!} - \sum_{i=m+2}^\infty \frac{m!^{i/m}}{i!}&\iff\\
\frac{m!^{1/m}}{m+1} &> \sum_{i=m+2}^\infty \frac{((m+1)!^{1/(m+1)}-m!^{1/m})^i}{i!}
\end{aligned}$$

> **Lema.** For $m\ge 1$ we have $(m+1)!^{1/(m+1)}-m!^{1/m}< 1$.

**Proof.** Freestyle approximations incoming...

$$\begin{aligned}
(m+1)!^{1/(m+1)}-m!^{1/m}
&<^1\frac{(m+1)(2\pi(m+1))^{1/2(m+1)}}{e^{1-1/12(m+1)^2}}-\frac{m(2\pi m)^{1/2m}}{e^{1-1/m(12m+1)}}\\
&<^2\frac{\pi^{1/2m}}{e^{1-1/12(m+1)^2}}\left((m+1)(2(m+1))^{1/2(m+1)}-m(2m)^{1/2m}\right)\\
&<^3\frac{2}{3}\left((m+1)(2(m+1))^{1/2(m+1)}-m(2m)^{1/2m}\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{3}\left((2(m+1))^{1/2(m+1)}+m((2(m+1))^{1/2(m+1)}-(2m)^{1/2m})\right)\\
&<^4\frac{2}{3}(2(m+1))^{1/2(m+1)}\\
&<^5\frac{2}{3}\sqrt2\\
&<1
\end{aligned}$$
as we wanted. $\square$

(1) [Stirling's inequality](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html): $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^{n}}{e^{n-1/(12n+1)}}<n!<\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^{n}}{e^{n-1/(12n)}}$.

(2) $e^{1-1/12(m+1)^2}>e^{1-1/m(12m+1)}$ and $\pi^{1/2m} > \pi^{1/2(m+1)}$.

(3) $\dfrac{\pi^{1/2m}}{e^{1-1/12(m+1)^2}}$ reaches its maximum for $m=1$ and $\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{e^{1-1/48}}\approx 0.66577\dots<\dfrac23$.

(4) $(2(m+1))^{1/2(m+1)}-(2m)^{1/2m}<0$.

(5) $\sqrt2$ is the maximum of $x^{1/x}$ for $x$ positive integer.

Therefore, it is enough to prove that
$$\frac{m!^{1/m}}{m+1}>\sum_{i=m+2}^\infty\frac{1}{i!}$$

Notice the RHS is the $(m+1)$th remainder of the exponential function's Taylor's series applied to $1$. Therefore, [Taylor's inequality](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorsInequality.html) on the interval $[0, 1]$ gives us

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=m+2}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}
&< \frac{e}{(m+2)!}\\
%&= e^x\frac{(m+1)(m+1)!^{1/(m+1)}-m!^{2/m}}{(m+2)(m+1)}\\
%&= e^x\frac{(m+1)^{(m+2)/(m+1)}m!^{1/(m+1)}-m!^{2/m}}{(m+2)(m+1)}\\
%&= e^xm!^{1/(m+1)}\frac{((m+1)^{(m+2)/(m+1)}-(m!^{1/m})^{(m+2)/(m+1)})}{(m+2)(m+1)}
\end{aligned}$$

Finally, it is enough to show that $\displaystyle \frac{e}{(m+2)!} < \frac{m!^{1/m}}{m+1}$, i.e., $e < (m+2)m!^{(m+1)/m}$, which can be easily verified since $m+2\ge 3$ and $m!^{(m+1)/m}>1$.

Comment: You did a very nice work and (+1)+(+1) for sure. As, I wrote, under one assumption, the result is immediate. I tried to use the fact that $(m!)^{\frac{1}{m}}$ is very close to a straight line but no success. $$(m!)^{\frac{1}{m}} < \frac{1}{12} e^{-\gamma } \left(\pi ^2 m+12\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

*Too long for a comment.*

As I commented in the deleted post, starting with $x=(m!)^{\frac{1}{m}}$, we have
$$S_m=\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}=e^x \left(1-\frac{\Gamma (m+1,x)}{\Gamma (m+1)}  \right)$$ Replacing $x$ by its definition, if you assume that $S$ is continuous and monotonic, it is decreasing
$$\color{red}{S_0=e^{e^{-\gamma }}-1}\qquad S_1=e-2\qquad S_2=e^{\sqrt{2}}-(2+\sqrt{2})$$ and its maximum value is given by $S_0$.

Just for the fun
$$S'_0=e^{e^{-\gamma }}\Bigg(\frac{\pi ^2}{12} e^{-\gamma } -G_{2,1}^{0,2}\left(e,\frac{1}{\gamma }|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)  \Bigg) =-0.0521627 $$